# Test for docstring existence

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to write unit test for Python that would check if every package, module, class and method has a `__doc__` string.

What is the right way to to this? I was thinking of making this check with recursive imports.

Comment: Note that tools like `pylint` already check for docstrings, so you might want to look into how they do it (or just use them).

Comment: I just found this, so I'm not sure if it's what you're after or not, but perhaps worth a look: https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html

Comment: I'm aware obout doctest but I don't want to write code without hinting, syntax checker, coloring etc... Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

Shout out to @jonrsharpe for hint obout pylint. :)

Make default .pylintrc with this command:

```
 pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc
```

Edit change docstring-min-length variable to:

```
 docstring-min-length=10
```

Then execute this script... echo will print the exit code from pylint test:

```
 pylint --disable=all --enable=missing-docstring <package-name>
 echo $?
```

If echo is 0 pylint passed else it failed.
Hope it hellps ;)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this, without using external programs like pylint, is to check if the functions **doc** attribute is None.

```
def f():
    pass

print(f.__doc__ is None) # Prints None.
```

Comment: This works perfect and clean. If you want to check if a class has a docstring: from package.module import class_name. Then just Class_name.__doc__ will print it's corresponding docstring.

Comment: Therefore, you can also directly access class docstring programmatically